# How to display a "by" object in long format

Tags: r, melt

The `by` function from base R has its own special output class, "by", which comes with a special print format. For ease of putting the results into tables, I'd really like to arrange the results of "by" as a data frame with columns indicating the levels of the factors used to subset:

```
b <- by(mtcars$mpg, list(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am), function(x) c(length(x), mean(x)))
some_reformatting_function(b)
#  am vs length     mean
#1  0  0     12 15.05000
#2  0  1      7 20.74286
#3  1  0      6 19.75000
#4  1  1      7 28.37143
```

When the `FUN` argument to `by` is of length one, I can hack this together by forcing the class of `b` to be numeric, then `melt`ing. But when `FUN` returns a longer vector, this approach doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `dplyr` instead?

Comment: @Gregor Just got it using `ddply` myself, actually, but thanks for the suggestion. I've been meaning to learn `dplyr` for some time now, and this adds yet another reason.

Answer (score 3):

`dplyr` is great for these tasks, and is very easy to learn.

`by` produces a tricky format to work with. One way of getting where you want to be without other packages from `by` is by using `by` again to combine the factors in a consistent way.

```
b <- by(mtcars$mpg, list(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am), function(x) c(length(x), mean(x)))
i <- by(cbind(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am), list(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am), function(x) c(x[1,1], x[1,2])) 
i <- unlist(i)
b <- unlist(b)
i <- matrix(i, ncol = 2)
b <- matrix(b, ncol = 2)
d <- data.frame(i, b)
names(d) <- c("am", "vs", "length", "mean")

d
#   am vs   length     mean
# 1  0  0 12.00000  6.00000
# 2  0  1 15.05000 19.75000
# 3  1  1  7.00000  7.00000
# 4  0  1 20.74286 28.37143
```

You could also combine the `by` function calls above.

Answer (score 2):

**1) aggregate**  For the specific example in the question one would normally use `aggregate` in base R rather than `by`:

```
aggregate(mpg ~ vs + am, mtcars, function(x) c(length = length(x), mean = mean(x)))
```

giving:

```
  vs am mpg.length mpg.mean
1  0  0   12.00000 15.05000
2  1  0    7.00000 20.74286
3  0  1    6.00000 19.75000
4  1  1    7.00000 28.37143
```

**2) by** If the actual problem is more complex and you do need to use `by` then to format a `by` object as in the question the `by` statement should be rewritten to operate on the entire data frame and to include the margining variables in the function:

```
fun <- function(x) with(x, 
             data.frame(vs = vs[1], am = am[1], length = length(mpg), mean = mean(mpg)))

do.call("rbind", by(mtcars, mtcars[c("vs", "am")], fun))
```

giving:

```
  vs am length     mean
1  0  0     12 15.05000
2  1  0      7 20.74286
3  0  1      6 19.75000
4  1  1      7 28.37143
```

**3) by using b from question** Although this is not recommmended it would be possible to reform the `b` in the question.  We have slightly restated `b` using more compact notation and adding names.  Realizing that the `"by"` object `b` is also a 2x2 matrix in this case we can convert it to a data frame, transpose it giving matrix `m`, get the margins from `b`'s row names giving `margins` and `cbind` everything together:

```
b <- by(mtcars$mpg, mtcars[c("vs", "am")], function(x) c(length=length(x), mean=mean(x)))

m <- t(do.call("data.frame", c(as.data.frame.matrix(b), check.names = FALSE)))
margins <- read.table(text = rownames(m), sep = ".", col.names = rev(names(dimnames(b))))
cbind(margins, m)
```

giving:

```
    am vs length     mean
0.0  0  0     12 15.05000
0.1  0  1      7 20.74286
1.0  1  0      6 19.75000
1.1  1  1      7 28.37143
```

**4) sqldf** It would also be possible to solve this particular problem using any of a number of packages such as data.table, doBy, dplyr and sqldf.  Here we show an sqldf solution:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select vs, am, count(*) length, avg(mpg) mean 
       from mtcars 
       group by vs, am")
```

giving:

```
  vs am length     mean
1  0  0     12 15.05000
2  0  1      6 19.75000
3  1  0      7 20.74286
4  1  1      7 28.37143
```

Comment: Your `2)` is exactly what I would do if I had only `by` to work with. It is actually still a handy function sometimes for working out the logic of a dplyr/group_by or data.table operation as it allows for returning lists and ugly intermediate steps.

Answer (score 1):

Had a sneaking suspicion right after I posted this that the answer was probably going to be "just use (one of Hadley's packages)", and sure enough, `ddply`'s default output format is the much more sensible data frame that I wanted.

```
plyr::ddply(mtcars, .variables = c("vs", "am"), function(x) c(nrow(x), mean(x[["mpg"]])))
#  vs am V1       V2
#1  0  0 12 15.05000
#2  0  1  6 19.75000
#3  1  0  7 20.74286
#4  1  1  7 28.37143
```

Comment: Rather than an anonymous function, you can just do, `..., summarize, n = nrow(mpg), mean = mean(mpg))`.

Comment: Comment correction: you'd need `n = length(mpg)`, not `nrow(mpg)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `data.table` solution is

```
library(data.table)
mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
mtcars[, .(length = .N, mean = mean(mpg)), by = .(vs, am)][order(am,vs)]
```

(thanks @thelatemail's suggestion, it is neater.)

Below is the output,

```
   vs am length     mean
1:  0  0     12 15.05000
2:  1  0      7 20.74286
3:  0  1      6 19.75000
4:  1  1      7 28.37143
```

Comment: General logic is fine, but you can cut a bit of the SD references out - `mtcars[, .(length = .N, mean = mean(mpg)), by = list(vs, am)][order(am,vs)]`

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks! I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` version is:

```
group_by(mtcars, am, vs) %>%
    summarize(n = n(),
              mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
```